# When parsing a string using mb_split() and implode(), how to identify multiple line jumps as new paragraphs?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

Here is my code:

```
$ParagArray=array('\r\n\r\n','\n\r\n\r','\r\r','\n\n');
foreach ($ParagArray as $value){
    $chunks=(mb_split($value,$text));
    $text=implode ("(PARAG)",$chunks);
}
echo "Here is the modified 1 text:<br/>";
echo $text;
echo "<br/>";

$LineArray=array('\r\n','\n\r','\r','\n');
foreach ($LineArray as $value){
    $chunks=(mb_split($value,$text));
    $text=implode ("(LINE)",$chunks);
}
echo "Here is the modified 2 text:<br/>";
echo $text;
echo "<br/>";
```

What I try to do here is identify paragraphs as being 2-line jumps, and carriage returns as being 1-line jumps.  I replace them respectively with `(PARAG)` and `(LINE)` tags.

My problem is that I end up with `(PARAG)(LINE)` when the text incorporates 3 line jumps, `(PARAG)(PARAG)` when the text incorporates 4-line jumps, etc.

Is there a way for me to modify my code to catch all the cases when there are 2 or more line jumps and replacing all the line jumps with a single `(PARAG)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\r\n\r\n|\n\r\n\r|\r\r|\n\n)[\r\n]*|(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/e', '"$1"? "(PARAG)": "(LINE)"', $str);
```

Comment: For this to work with unicode (utf-8), I would need to replace `/e'` with `/eu'`, right?